# Performance, writing multiple files in multiple threads to the same directory

Tags: windows, multithreading, io

First off I'd like to apologise if this has been answered somewhere else here on SO. Since I couldn't find any questions specific for what I need I decided to ask.

**Problem:** I need to receive multiple data packets from a device (scanner for example) and store these in disk. My approach was to queue the data packets and have a thread wait until there were enough items in the queue and start a thread that would consume a batch of data packets and store them in disk, the directory in which they are stored doesn't change so multiple threads can, possibly, write to the same directory at the same time.

A collegue of mine mentioned that this was a bad idea since having multiple threads write to the same disk would actually slow it down. Having googled this, I found that there was no clear answer to whether this was true or not, some stated that this isn't a problem for modern computers while others said this wouldn't be a problem if different threads were writing to separate disks like in a RAID setup.

**Question:** Is writing to the same disk with multiple threads (which are writing a  batch of data packet files) a bad idea? Or is there actual benefits to doing so?

**P.S:** I'd like to add that the solution for this will be for the Windows OS.

Thanks!

Comment: This is the sort of thing that varies widely depending on the hardware involved, so only real why to know is to try it both ways and measure the results.  That said, see this post:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5858198/is-it-useful-to-use-multithreading-to-handle-files-on-a-hard-drive/5861721#5861721

Comment: Re, "same directory." That won't make any difference.  A directory is not a container for files in most modern file systems:  It's merely a data structure that the OS uses to _find_ a file when given a pathname of the file. Once the file has been found, the identities of the directories that were consulted during the pathname lookup no longer matters.

Comment: @besmirched Yes indeed, I meant since the write opertations were done sequentially within the same directory I would expect that the locality of the data on disk would be close to each other.

Comment: @JeremyFriesner I was afraid this would be the case. The link is insightful as to how multithreading might speed up writes, but this would only apply for an hdd. In which case, would you say that for an ssd it would actually be at all beneficial?

Comment: Re, locality on the disk:  See Jeremy Friesner's comment: The idea of "locality" is dependent on what file system you are using and, on whether it's a spinning disk or an SSD. There are so many possibilities these days... Unless you are writing code for a specific hardware configuration, It's probably best not to worry about that. If you think your application is going to need to run on a platform that performs better than a big laptop, then it may be time to start thinking about cluster computing/cloud computing solutions.

Comment: @besmirched The idea is to maximize the speed of the writes since the throughput of the device is real-time and can be very high. If required we would end up configuring the hardware to take advantage of this, but I wanted to know what the possibilities are, the OS can be a bit of a black box nowadays.

Comment: @Belfer4 since SSDs have no seek-time penalty, I think the only way multiprocessing could help with an SSD is if your program is CPU-bound (in which case using multiple cores to distribute the CPU-load could speed things up).  The thing to do is to measure your disk's raw write speed (using your favorite utility), and then measure your program's write speed.  If the former is significantly more than the latter, then your program has room for improvement; if not, then you're I/O-limited and that's the best you can do without buying faster storage hardware.