# Is reading from disk with two threads faster?

Tags: multithreading

Let's say I have a big 200 GiB file.

It's stored on disk in on piece (sequential and not fragmented).

The disk is connected via SATA III or PCIe (M.2).

The buffer size (when calling *read*) is selected big (1 GiB).
So increasing this won't make it faster.

Will reading the file with two threads be faster?

Comment: Benchmark both options.  Then realize whatever result you get is applicable only to the system you ran your benchmarks on.

Comment: My guess is it would be slower.

Comment: Possible duplicate of:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5858198/is-it-useful-to-use-multithreading-to-handle-files-on-a-hard-drive

Comment: definitely not. All read operations from the same device are essentially sequential due to the sequential nature of the device, which is the slowest part of the computer.